# window.open auto resize height and width according to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm passing the div value to a window.open popup that should resize height according to content, however when i used auto it just opens a new window. I tried this code but wouldn't work

```
  function openPopup() {

            var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
            var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=auto');
            var doc = myWindow.document;
            doc.open();
            doc.write(divText);
            doc.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use JQuery window, because when you're using window.open, PopupBlocker will cause problems for you. Also window in this way has so limitations, but in JQuery window you can show dynamic content and it works like a charm.

By the way, if you have to do this way, "height" property of window does not have "auto" value. So you should handle "onload" event in the page opening in popup window and calculate everything and resize the window at the time window is loaded.

Cheers

Comment: Yeap. exactly. that's what you need dear.

Comment: Few years later, I would say that it is a good advice for all cases. If you want to load a pdf content, for example, I would recommend to directly open a browser window.

Comment: @Okipa — I disagree: a modal dialog is no new window whatsoever. Although I do make heavy use of jQuery dialogs, I occasionally want to display visual elements _outside_ the current window — a very useful feature when you have a large screen or additional ones. A jQ dialog being a child of window.document, you will never make, while window.open will —and that is what 'pop-up ' windows (strange name, after all…) are meant for.